# I am working on a game project on unity and I am stuck at a camera problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera-calibration

It has two camera angles. First person for engaging gameplay and top-down for 2D game experience. But in top down camera view I can't figure out the rotation of the camera with respect to player.

I wrote the following script for the main(top-down) camera view.

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f, 24.953f, -0f);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}`
```

I tried
 `transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;`
but it didn't work since camera is on top of player. If I could somehow do
`transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation + X axis 90 degree;`
That would be perfect but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to follow the player from above with your second camera. Leaving some flexibility, the best option I think would be Unity's built in `Transform.LookAt(target)` method ([LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)), which automatically rotates an object (in your case the camera) so that it faces the target.

Therefore, you could do something like this in your `Update`, assuming your script is attached to the Camera. Otherwise substitute `transform` with `Camera.main.transform`:

```
transform.LookAt(player);
```

Note: If you plan to have your camera fixed above your player at all times, it is sufficient if you perform the `LookAt` once, e.g. in `Start` and then attach the camera as a child to the player. If your camera does not move with your player in the world but you want it to focus the player anyway, do do it in `Update`. Hope I addressed your problem:)

Comment: I want camera to be always on top of player and only it's Y-axis rotation should coincide with player's rotation

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been resolved. I was trying to rotate the wrong axis. My bad.

```
mouseInput = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * speed * -mouseInput);
```

I needed to get mouse input from user and change the Z-axis according to it. Game is working fine now.